# How to Call API After set text date changed

Tags: java, android, datepicker, calendar

I want to call an API when the text of a date changes. When activity opens I set some initial dates, from and to dates. If the user changes those dated I want to call one API. Please, help.

```
private void setListener() {


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            StringBuilder  selectedFromDate = new StringBuilder().append(dayOfMonth).append("-").append(monthOfYear + 1).append("-").append(year);
           TextFromDate.setText(selectedFromDate);

        }
    },


    calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
          TextFromDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
            datePickerDialog.show();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really simple :

```
private void setListener() {


Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        StringBuilder  selectedFromDate = new StringBuilder().append(dayOfMonth).append("-").append(monthOfYear + 1).append("-").append(year);
       TextFromDate.setText(selectedFromDate);
       //***Call your server call here. As this method is called when you select a date.***
    }
},


        calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
      TextFromDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
        datePickerDialog.show();



    }
});
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hai my api call method is  getOrderSummary();.i did as u said ,but when i debugg after change date that method is skipping..not calling